# Construct a PDE solution from a net of approximations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, approximation-theory, linear-pde, schwartz-distributions

Consider $P$ a linear partial differential operator in $\Bbb R ^n$. Consider some boundary condition given in the generic form $C(u) = 0$, that guarantees a unique solution (if any) of $Pu = 0$.

Let $(u_i)_{i \in I}$ be a net of distributions such that $\lim \limits _{i \in I} P u_i = 0$ and $\lim \limits _{i \in I} C(u_i) = 0$. Is it possible, then, to conclude that there exist a distribution $u$ such that $\lim \limits _{i \in I} u_i = u$, $Pu = 0$ and $C(u) = 0$?

Playing with words, if I have a net of approximate solutions of a PDE, are its elements approximations of a solution of that PDE? That is, can I use them to construct a solution?

(I have chosen to work with distributions since they seem the most convenient, feel free to modify this context suiting your needs. If stronger hypotheses are needed, please say so in comments below and I shall edit my question to reflect this.)

Comment: How is this different from asking whether $f(x_i)$ converges to $f(x)$ when $x_i$ converges to $x$ on a general topological space? Obviously they agree when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation in which one naturally has a net of a solution of a PDE which is not a sequence. But maybe that's only my limited imagination…

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I guess the difference is that the OP does not assume that $x_i$ converges to $x$ but only that $f(x)$ converges to zero and wants to conclude the convergence of the $x_i$.

Comment: @Dirk, if that is the case, then there are obvious counter examples like $P=d/dx$ and $u_i = i$ (constant functions) with $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Dirk: In my problem, the index set $I$ is the set of all the partitions of a given set, hence nets instead of sequences.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine: To put my problem in your notations, I have $f(x_i) \to 0$ but I do not have $x$. I have good reasons to believe that it must exist, though. Concerning your counterexample, I have added further data concerning the boundary condition that rules it out - thank you for making the statement more precise.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine This counterexample does not work with unique solutions (as requested by the OP or the edited question with explicit boundary conditions).

Comment: @AlexM. I guess that your limit is something like "largest set in the partition goes to zero".  Why not pick sequences of such converging partitions and show that limits are independent of the subsequences?

Comment: I guess you are only interested in strong solutions?  There are certainly examples of sequences of continuous functions that satisfy your conditions, but their limit is discontinuous, so not a strong solution of the PDE.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson: Since I already work with distributions, what would "weak" mean? Can one get "weaker" than distributions?

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully.